# Connecting to janus server always hangs with hangup message from janus

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc, janus-gateway

I have problem connecting to janus `janus.plugin.videoroom` plugin from iOS device using swift.
Although every steps take place correctly but janus server send following message:

```
{
   "janus": "hangup",
   "session_id": 3201104494179497,
   "sender": 7759980289270843,
   "reason": "ICE failed"
}
```

and disconnect.

Debugging the messages of connecting to janus leads me to following:

1- RTCIceGatheringState never changes to Completed

2- The generated candidates are like following:

```
candidate:3215141415 1 udp 1686052607 w.x.y.z 57168 typ srflx raddr w.x.y.z rport 57168 generation 0 ufrag 340a network-id 1 network-cost 10
```

as you can see video and audio words are replaced by 1 and 0 respectively in the generated candidate.

Do you have any idea about these two observations!

And why janus send the `"ICE failed"` message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the reason of getting `"hang up"` message is because I did not set the received jsep (from janus) to my peerconnection.
after setAnswer the jsep "hang up" message gone!

> 1- RTCIceGatheringState never changes to Completed

For the problem of not having `"Completed"` state For `RTCIceGatheringState` was because of `"continualGatheringPolicy"` options in configuring the peerConnection which was set to `"gatherContinually"` after setting that to `"gatherOnce"` the Completed state seen! :)

> 2- The generated candidates are like following:

It seem this is normal to have audio/video or 0/1